# (Laravel) there is class AuthenticatesUsers is used by LoginCotroller where is it located?

Tags: laravel

(Laravel) there is class AuthenticatesUsers in LoginCotroller where is it located ?

LoginCotroller is using AuthenticatesUsers but where is it ? 
I was trying to search but it's failed 
[There is nothing like AuthenticatesUsers in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYnS1.png)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trait **AuthenticatesUsers** found on laravel/ui package ,after install package you can find trait on

> vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend

Answer (score 0):

for auth routing they located in :

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing
```

this file contain some thing like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY0fG.png)

the AthenticatesUsesrs.php trait located in:

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth
```

*note : vendor file is in `.gitignore` file and when you push your files to github change no setting, for solve this problem you can overwrite functions in your **LoginController**.*